# Parsing Text String into Fields Using R, I have Start Points and Field Lengths

Tags: r, string

Following is the text string I have which is in a text file (file contains 160,000 line items).

> 999999XYZGHI BCDNIXYZ 161 COLUMBIA AVE  NEWARK NJ07106     19800128F973XXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYR4234076
>
> Index: Field - Start Point/Length
>
> [IDENTIFIER - 1/6, LAST_NAME - 7/20, FIRST_NAME - 27/12, ADDRESS1 - 39/30, ADDRESS2 - 69/30, CITY - 99/30, STATE - 129/2, ZIP - 131/10, DOB - 141/8, etc......]

I am attempting to convert this text file data into Excel like columns for further analysis (Excel Crashes all the time, as the line items are too many).

Comment: You should edit your text, follow the instructions.

Comment: Thtanks #Soheil, guess I would learn the right way to ask questions as well, as I go Along!

Comment: You could use `substr`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `read.fwf()` to read the file in R.

```
read.fwf("file.csv",width=c(6,20,12,30...),
  col.names=c("IDENTIFIER","LAST_NAME","FIRST_NAME","ADDRESS1"...))
```